# How can we resume the script from where it left off after resume in Linux Ubuntu? Is anyway we can make use of rc.local?

Tags: kernel, scripts

How the rc.local can be used to resume the script after resume?

Some explanation from user's comment:

```
Boot_desired_kernel() {} 
# after this system will reboot 
Do_task(){} 
Do_task() /*
```

Using the pasting the file in init.d and updating it is working for script to run after reboot but what I am expecting is the script should start where it left off before reboot

Comment: How the rc.local can be used to resume the script after system reboot?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, how to do it using `rc.local`, but maybe you will be satisfied with `systemd` way:

- Create the new systemd service:

  ```
  sudo vim.tiny /etc/systemd/system/startscript.service
  ```

  You could `nano` instead of `vim.tiny` or other editor you like
  Paste the next to it:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Start script after resume
  After=suspend.target

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/full/path/to/the/script.sh

  [Install]
  WantedBy=suspend.target
  ```
- Enable and start the service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable startscript && sudo systemctl start startscript
  ```

Comment: Using the pasting the file in init.d and updating it is working for script to run after reboot but what I am expecting is the script should start where it left off before reboot

Comment: Show an example of script you want to resume. Does Resume in your case is reboot?

Comment: Boot_desired_kernel()                                                                                                               {} # after this system will reboot  
Do_task(){}   
Do_task() /*

Comment: Resume and reboot are very different things. As I see you want to reboot into a specific kernel and run some commands just after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resume script execution after reboot, but you could check kernel version and if the kernel version is what you need, you could execute the rest of the script skipping the kernel changing and rebooting part as in the next script. But the script will be executed before the first reboot and after each reboot.

```
#!/bin/bash

kernel="5.3.0-40-generic"

if [[ $(uname -a) != *$kernel* ]]; then
    kernlist="$(grep -i "menuentry '" /boot/grub/grub.cfg|sed -r "s|--class .*$||g")"
    printf "%s$kernlist\n" | logger
    menuline="$(printf "%s$kernlist\n"|grep -ne $kernel | grep -v recovery | cut -f1 -d":")"
    menunum="$(($menuline-2))"
    grub-reboot "1>$menunum"
    echo "The next grub's menu entry will be choosen after the reboot:\n 1>$menunum" | logger
    reboot
fi

if [[ $(uname -a) == *$kernel* ]];
  then echo "This command is executed after reboot to $kernel" | logger;
fi

echo "Currently running kernel version is: $(uname -r)" | logger
```

After reboot it skips running kernel selecting part if the current kernel is of required version and echoes "This command is executed after reboot to KERNEL_VERSION_HERE" if you run `journalctl -b | grep This` or:

```
$ journalctl -b | grep Currently
Apr 13 17:35:51 lenovo root[1013]: Currently running kernel version is: 5.3.0-40-generic
```

After adding this to `systemd` it loads with default kernel and then automatically reboots and boots with 5.3.0-40-generic kernel.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/resscript.service 
[Unit]
Description=Start script after reboot
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/test/resscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you for the input , I try to work this out

Comment: Tried the same exact step , seems to be not working for me

Comment: Make sure you have spaces in `if` statements like this: `$(uname -a) == *$kernel*`. If You've edited the text without spaces before and after `==` it will not work: `$(uname -a)==*$kernel*` - don't do so. And also, what `journalctl -b | grep Currently` shows in your case?